# Simple Mysqli Update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am just beginer to php.I am bangging my head for this simple form update.
First i did this with prepare statements,that is not working at last I setteled with simple mysqli query.I don't know where it goes wrong.
Any help will be greatfull.

profile.php

```
   <?php
   session_start();
     include 'db.php';
     if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header("location:login.php");
     }

    //echo $_SESSION['id'].$_SESSION['username'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Landed by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profile</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeass/assets/css/main.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <h1 id="logo"><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></h1>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">News Feed</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="logout.php" class="button special">Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>

            <!-- Main -->
                <div id="main" class="wrapper style1">
                    <div class="container">
                        <header class="major">
                            <h2>Profile</h2>
                            <p>Edit your stored information</p>
                        </header>




                        <!-- Form -->
                            <section>

<?php
  $uid = $_SESSION['id'];
   $getdata = "SELECT name,email,bloodgroup,mobile,relative_mob1,relative_mob2,message  FROM users WHERE id = ?";
   $stmtget = $con->prepare($getdata);
   $stmtget->bind_param("i",$uid);
   $stmtget->execute();
   $stmtget->bind_result($gname,$gemail,$gbloodgroup,$gmobile,$gremob1,$gremob2,$gmes);

   $stmtget->fetch();
    $stmtget->store_result();
   $stmtget->close();
   //echo $gname;

 ?>
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {
                  // echo $_SESSION['username'];
                 $file = $_SESSION['username']."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
                 $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                 $folder="uploads/";
                 if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file)){
                 $sql = "UPDATE users SET pic = ? WHERE id = ?";
                 $stmti = $con->prepare($sql);
                $stmti->bind_param("si",$file,$uid);
                 $stmti->execute();



}

}
$get = "SELECT pic FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$stmtg = $con->prepare($get);
$stmtg->bind_param("i",$uid);
$stmtg->execute();
$stmtg->bind_result($img);
$stmtg->fetch();
//echo '<img src="uploads/'.$img.'"  width="50" height="50"/>';

                ?>
                <section>
                                <h3>Image</h3>
                                <h4>Profile Pic</h4>
                                <div class="box alt">
                                    <div class="4u  6u(xsmall)"><span class="image fit"><?php echo '<img src="uploads/'.$img.'"  width="100" height="200"/>'; ?></span></div>

                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </section>
                <div class="probut">
                <form action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                  <input type="file" name="file" />
                                    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
                                            </form>
                                          </div>

                                <form method="post" action="profile.php">
                                    <div class="row uniform 50%">

                                    <!--    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="file" name="file"/></div> -->

                                        <h4>Name</h4>

                                        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                            <input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo $gname ?>" placeholder="Name" />

                                        </div>
                                        <h4>Email</h4>
                                        <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $gemail ?>" placeholder="Email" />
                                        </div>
                                        <h4>Blood Group</h4>
                                        <div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)">
                                            <input type="text" name="bloodgroup" id="name" value="<?php echo $gbloodgroup ?>" placeholder="Blood Group" />
                                        </div>
                                        <h4>Your Mobile number</h4>
                                        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                            <input type="tel" name="mobile" id="name" value="<?php echo $gmobile ?>" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                                        </div>

                                        <h4>Relatives Mob number 1</h4>
                                        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                            <input type="tel" name="remob1" id="name" value="<?php echo $gremob1 ?>" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                                        </div>

                                        <h4>Relatives Mob number 2</h4>
                                        <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
                                            <input type="tel" name="remob2" id="name" value="<?php echo $gremob2 ?>" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                                        </div>

                                        <h4>Default Message</h4>
                                        <div class="12u$">
                                        <!--    <textarea name="message" id="name" value="value" placeholder="" rows="6"></textarea> -->
                      <input type="tel" name="message" id="name"  value="<?php echo $gmes ?>" placeholder="Message" />



                                        </div>
                                        <div class="12u$">
                                            <ul class="actions">
                                                <li><input type="submit" name="submitttt" value="Save" class="special" /></li>

                                                <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
        <?php



                  if (isset($_POST['submitttt'])) {
                     $nameu = $_POST['name'];
                    $bloodgroupu = $_POST['bloodgroup'];
                    $mobileu = $_POST['mobile'];
                    $remob1u = $_POST['remob1'];
                    $remob2u = $_POST['remob2'];
                    $messageu = $_POST['message'];





                   $newsql = "UPDATE users SET name = '".$nameu."',bloodgroup = '".$bloodgroupu."',mobile = '".$mobileu."',relative_mob1 = '".$remob1u."',relative_mob2 = '".$remob2u."',message = '".$messageu."' WHERE id  = ".$uid."" ;
                     if (mysqli_query($con,$newsql)) {
                        echo "Updated";
                      } else{
                        echo "Not updated";
                        echo "query failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
                      }
                       echo '<h1>'.$uid.'</h1>';
                       echo $newsql;
                                           /*$up = "UPDATE users SET name = ?,bloodgroup = ?,mobile = ?,relative_mob1 = ?,relative_mob2 = ?,message = ? WHERE id  = ?";
                    $stmtuppp = $con->prepare($up);
                    $stmtuppp->bind_param("ssssssi",$nameu,$bloodgroupu,$mobileu,$remob1u,$remob2u,$messageu,$uid);
                    $stmtuppp->execute();
                    echo '<script>alert("updated")</script>';
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";*/

                    /*echo $nameu.'<br>';
                    echo $bloodgroupu;
                    echo $mobileu;
                    echo $remob1u;
                    echo  $remob2u;
                    echo $messageu;*/

                  }


        ?>

                            </section>


                    </div>
                </div>


            <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                    <ul class="icons">
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; Yelp Mee. All rights reserved.</li><li>Design: <a>3rd Year CSE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="homeass/assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you find an example out there of a prepared UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your set value inside quotes as

```
$newsql = "UPDATE users SET name = '".$nameu."',bloodgroup = '".$bloodgroupu."',mobile = '".$mobileu."',relative_mob1 = '".$remob1u."',relative_mob2 = '".$remob2u."',message = '".$messageu."' WHERE id  = '".$uid."'" ;
```

To check error in query use

```
if (!$con->query($newsql)) {
echo "query failed: (" . $con->errno . ") " . $con->error;
}
```

Your code is open for sql injection check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent it.

Also read about bind statement

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Updated using bind statement

```
$newsql = "UPDATE users SET name = ?,bloodgroup = ?,mobile = ?,relative_mob1 = ?,relative_mob2 = ?,message = ? WHERE id  = ?" ;
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssi', $nameu, $bloodgroupu, $mobileu, $remob1u, $remob2u, $messageu, $uid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: failed: (2014) Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now......this is error message im getting...

Comment: first try to update only one value ....

Comment: echo your query and check what it return!! Then run your query directly into phpmyadmin and look for error

Comment: also post your full code!!

Comment: I've updated my full code.But still it is not working @Saty

Comment: Please follow following link for that error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077779/php-mysqli-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798762/mysqli-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now

Comment: Saty, likewise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514649/php-mysql-bind-param-how-to-prepare-statement-for-update-query

Comment: I know about prepare statement. I also provide the link of it. @Strawberry

Comment: In which case, I think you're answer is misleading, given the context of the question.

Comment: @Strawberry i think updated part make sense!!

Comment: Yes. I'd be tempted to omit the first half of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Need to add single quotes around the field values.

**Corrected Code:**

```
$newsql = "UPDATE users SET name = '".$nameu."',bloodgroup = '".$bloodgroupu."',mobile = '".$mobileu."',relative_mob1 = '".$remob1u."',relative_mob2 = '".$remob2u."',message = '".$messageu."' WHERE id  = '".$uid."'" ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at your query:

```
$newsql = "UPDATE users SET name = ".$nameu.",bloodgroup = ".$bloodgroupu.",mobile = ".$mobileu.",relative_mob1 = ".$remob1u.",relative_mob2 = ".$remob2u.",message = ".$messageu." WHERE id  = ".$uid."" ;
```

And notice you have missed quotes `'`

```
$newsql = "UPDATE users SET name = '".$nameu."',bloodgroup = '".$bloodgroupu."',mobile = '".$mobileu."',relative_mob1 = '".$remob1u."',relative_mob2 = '".$remob2u."',message = '".$messageu."' WHERE id  = ".$uid."" ;
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_string_escape` and `addslashes` is not secure for sql injection . Better to use bind statement!!

Comment: @Saty yes I agree prepared statements with bind params are always secure that both above.

Comment: So please remove that part form your answer and add about bind statement to make your answer better and correct

Comment: The scope of the question is just to correct errors in query.

Comment: Still you have syntax error in your code. Please look into this